# odoo 10 backend development

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

> I am working on odoo 10.I want to change logo of odoo and database dropdown in login page. Answer related to this question couldnt solve the problem.
>       my tries:
>       1- created a mytheme module 
>       2- created manifest and init 
>       3- written view by inheriting template webclient_template.xml
>
> my view as shown below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <openerp>
      <data>
      <template id="assets_backend" name="mytheme assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend"><xpath expr="." position="inside"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/mytheme/static/src/css/base.css"/><script type="text/javascript" src="/mytheme/static/src/js/mytheme.js"></script></xpath>
    </template><template id="mytheme.login_layout" inherit_id="web.login_layout" name="My Theme Login">
    <xpath expr="//div[@class='oe_single_form_footer']" position="replace">
      <div class="oe_single_form_footer">Here you can write your login footer</div>
     </xpath>
     <xpath expr="//div[@class='oe_single_form_logo']" position="replace">
     <div class="oe_single_form_logo">
     <img src="/mytheme/static/src/img/logo.png"
      alt="My Theme Logo" title="My Theme Logo" />
     </div>
     </xpath>
     </template>
     </data>
     </openerp>
```

> my manifest shown below  **manifest**.py:

```
 {
            'name': 'mytheme', 
            'version': '0.1', 
            'depends': ['base','web'], 
            'external_dependencies': {},
            'data': ['views/webclient_templates.xml'],
            'js': ['static/src/js/mytheme.js'],
            'css': ['static/src/css/base.css'], 
            'installable': True,
            'auto_install':True,
            'active':True,
 }
```

> Another question is what i supposed to write for js file ??
>            my base file to clear the database selection as shown below:

base.css:

```
<templates>
<!-- Templates modified at the web start, before loading of a database. -->

<!-- Remove the Manage database link, but keep the Powered by OpenERP-->
<
t t-extend="Login">
    <t t-jquery="div.oe_login_footer" t-operation="replace">
        <a href="http://www.openerp.com" target="_blank">Powered by <span>OpenERP</span></a>
    </t>
</t>
</templates
```

> ```
> Used links:
>
> https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-we-removing-link-that-appear-on-login-page-of-openerp-odoo-54623
> ```

Comment: If you change the company logo then it will automatically change in database login page as well as database drop-down menu page.

Comment: is there any way to extend the existing template and customize it.. if anyone knows please respond

Comment: add screen short which logo you want to change login screen logo or database selection logo?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO97L.png @ADVALAKI

Comment: change company logo in database it automatically reflect here.

Answer (score 1):

There are several conditions for you to be able to change the database selection page.

You may have remarked that if you have two databases, if you install a module in one of them and do not in the other, views created by the module will not exist in the second database. So for your view inheritance to work (which is also a view), it must be installed in the database you're viewing.

Even better, there are page that are not tied to a database. An example of those pages is the database selection page. If you researched a bit, you'd find that this page is generated as a view in the module web : how can this be ? I have not installed the module web --explicitly !

But hey, Odoo did it for you. There is this directive `'auto_install': True` in his manifest. This should be helping. But not sufficient. Why ? Because auto-installed module still require a database.

You still have to make it so that your module is a server wide module. A server wide module is a module that is installed and available even without database and in all databases. An example would be the `web` module. You can also have a look at [this one](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/dbfilter_from_header/) which is a smaller module and maybe easier to study.

So, to the matter at hand : you must create a module that is auto-installed by default and is a server wide module. In which you'd inherit the templates of the web module (there is a template for the login and database selection ; you seem to know how to do that so I'm counting on you ;) ). Then you just restart your server with `--load=web,web_kanban,your_module` or you specify `your_module` in the configuration file used by your Odoo process.

Hope this helps, have a nice day.

And for the javascript, this is how it's done :

```
<template id="notification_js" name="JS Notification" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
    <xpath expr="." position="inside">
        <script src="/myModule/static/src/js/Notification.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/myModule/static/src/js/Orders.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Comment: hello @manjikat can u explain how to write the view without db?

Comment: @SanuKyadav What exactly you want to achieve. Can you explain a bit more?